# How to apply either of two decorators to a view

Tags: python, django

I have two decorator functions - `authenticate` and `authenticate_remote`. At this moment I have to use them in turn in this manner:

```
@authenticate
def view_local(request):
    ...

@authenticate_remote
def view_remote(request):
    ...
```

where `view_local` and `view_remote` have absolutely identical code. What I want is something like:

```
@authenticate or @authenticate_remote
def view_one(request):
    ...
```

In this case I would not have to copy paste too much and clone similar code here and there.

Comment: Why not use the none-`@` syntax - `view_local = authenticate(view_one)` and `view_remote = authenticate_remote(view_one)`? You could even have a function that applies both and returns two versions: `view_local, view_remote = authenticate_both(view_one)`.

Comment: @  jonrsharpe. And don't you know how to move `authenticate` and `authenticate_remote` to urls.py? Can I do something like: `urlpatters = [url(r'^login/',authenticate(view.login))]` ?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to refactor code and use `authenticate_both`, like you said. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are callables that take in a function and return often the same function. So unfortunately you cannot perform a boolean operation on decorators.

Having said that, there are some possibilities that can be done:

1. You can use the notation `authenticate(view_one)` and `authenticate_remote(view_one)` in your `urls.py` (also on comment by @jonrsharpe).
2. If for some reason not profound to me you have some complex `urls.py` and you cannot do that, you can continue to have two functions with decorators, both pointing to a third function with the common code, thus avoiding repeatance:

   ```
   @authenticate
   def view_local(request):
       view_one(request)

   @authenticate_remote
   def view_remote(request):
       view_one(request)

   def view_one(request):
       # common code
   ```
3. Last, you can always provide your own decorator that uses both the other two on the provided function and then use that decorator on `view_one`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do:

```
def view_one(request):
    # common code

view_local = authenticate(view_one)
view_remote = authenticate_remote(view_one)
```

It's simple, explicit, and keeps the logic out of your `urls` module.